# Array.prototype = многократное использование

Tags: javascript, массивы, native

Проблема заключается в том, что окно браузера просто зависает при выполнении js кода более нескольких раз.

```
var getNoHide = dcm.querySelectorAll('[click-nohide]'),
    setHide   = dcm.querySelectorAll('[hide]');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(setHide, function(setHide) {
    setHide.style.display="none";   
});    

function click_hide(){
    click_nohide = Array.prototype.forEach.call(getNoHide, function(getNoHide) {

    var value = getNoHide.getAttribute('click-nohide'),
    getIdHide = dcm.getElementById(value);
    getNoHide.style.cursor="pointer";
    getNoHide.addEventListener('click', function(){
       getNoHide.removeAttribute('click-nohide');
       getNoHide.setAttribute('click-hide', value);     
       getIdHide.style.display="block";
       getNoHide.addEventListener('click', function(){
           getNoHide.removeAttribute('click-hide');
           getNoHide.setAttribute('click-nohide', value);       
           getIdHide.style.display="none";
           return click_hide();
          });
       });
   });      
}

click_hide();
```

**Обновление**

Должен он скрывать / отображать по клику элементы, в которых есть селектор.

```
function click_nohide(){
        Array.prototype.some.call(getNoHide, function(getNoHide) {

             var value = getNoHide.getAttribute('click-nohide'),
                 getIdHide = dcm.getElementById(value);
                 getNoHide.style.cursor="pointer";

                    getNoHide.onclick = function(){

                        getIdHide.style.display="block";
                        getNoHide.removeAttribute('click-nohide');
                        getNoHide.setAttribute('click-hide', value);
                        getHide = dcm.querySelectorAll('[click-hide]');
                        click_hide();
                    };


        });
}
 click_nohide();

//click-nohide  

function click_hide(){
        Array.prototype.some.call(getHide, function(getHide) {

             var value = getHide.getAttribute('click-hide'),
                 getIdHide = dcm.getElementById(value);
                 getHide.style.cursor="pointer";

                    getHide.onclick = function(){

                        getIdHide.style.display="none";
                        getHide.removeAttribute('click-hide');
                        getHide.setAttribute('click-nohide', value);
                        click_nohide();
                    };


        });
}
 click_hide();
};
```

Вот так, если.

Comment: ой-вэй, мои глаза, куда же навешивать столько одинаковых обработчиков клика? да еще и постоянно вызывать их друг из друга? **Каждый** вызов `getNoHide.addEventListener('click',` **добавляет** обработчик

Comment: Ну и стоит добавить описание, что же все-таки должен делать этот код?

Comment: _forEach_ - это метод, который _ничего_ не возвращает, поэтому нет смысла делать _click_nohide = Array.prototype.forEach.call(...)_ переменная _click_nohide_ - всегда будет _undefined_